# How to swap ViewControllers in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I learned the basics of building a iOS app with Swift.
I want to do something but I'm not sure on how to build it, I have a tab bar controller with two item "Home" and "Account".
I want "Account" to display : 
- LoginViewController if user is not logged
- AccountViewController if user is logged

How can I do that ? 
I think, maybe with a ByPassController which redirect to LoginViewController or AccountViewController ? Then "Account" will always display ByPassController. But I want to ear some advices.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the second tab to an `AccountViewController`. Then, in the `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` callback, check if the user is signed in. If the user is not signed in, replace the ViewController with a `LoginViewController`:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([tabBarController selectedIndex] == 1 && !user.isSignedIn)
    {
        //fill an array with all the view controllers in the UITabBarController
        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[tabBarController viewControllers]];

        //inistantiate login view controller
        UIViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController] init];

        //replace the second UIViewController in the array with LoginViewController
        [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject: loginViewController];

        //set array
        [tabBarController setViewControllers:arr];

    }
}
```

After the user logs-in, replace the second tab with the `AccountViewController`

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a Boolean that states the login state.
If use isn't logged in, just present a view controller with login fields.

```
let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(kMyViewControllerId) as! MyViewController
self.presentViewController(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And just dismiss it upon logging in.

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```